# How can I use something like `package::%to%` in a function/package

Tags: r, expss

I want to use functions from the `expss` package in my own functions/packages. I usually call the functions along with their packages (e.g. `dplyr::mutate(...)`).

The expss package has a function/operator `%to%`, and I don't know how I can do the same here, i.e. `expss::%to%` doesn't work, neither does `expss::'%to%'`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infix operators must be attached to be usable; you can’t use them prefixed with the package name.<sup>1</sup>

Inside a package, the conventional way is to add an `importFrom` directive to your `NAMESPACE` file or, if you’re using ‘roxygen2’, add the following Roxygen directive somewhere:

```
#' @importFrom expss %to%
```

Outside of package code, you could use [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/) to attach just the operator:

```
box::use(expss[`%to%`])
```

Or you can use simple assignment (this is the easiest solution in the simplest case but it becomes a lot of distracting code for multiple operators):

```
`%to%` = expss::`%to%`
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Except using regular function call syntax:

```
expss::`%to%`(…)
```

Comment: Thanks, the easy ``%to%` = expss::`%to%`` works in my case for testing purposes. For package usage I will use the importFrom.

Comment: You can also do `library(expss, include.only = "%to%")`

Comment: @moodymudskipper Kinda, but not really. This functionality is broken: calling it twice in a row with different arguments for the same package will silently ignore the second call. This alone (even ignoring the unergonomic syntax) effectively makes it unusable. By contrast, `box::use()` does the correct thing.